# IOS word game. Validate word performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, cpu-word

I'm building a scrabble game, and having some problem with the word dictionary. It contains ~700,000 words, and about 18 MB big.

Right now, I'm loading the whole dict into an array, which takes 12 seconds on an iPhone 4.

```
wordList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingString:@"/wordlist.plist"]];
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way to load the wordlist faster and/or reduce memory?
2. It takes about 12 seconds to get all possible words from a set of letters. Is it possible to make it quicker? Here's the code:

   ```
   -(NSMutableArray *)getValidWords:(NSString *)letters{
       NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

       for (int i = 0, c = [wordList count]; i < c; i++){
       if ([self isWordValid: [wordList objectAtIndex: i] forLetters:letters]){
           [list addObject:[wordList objectAtIndex: i]];
       }
   }

   return list;
   ```

   }

   ```
   - (BOOL)isWordValid:(NSString *)word forLetters:(NSString *)ltrs{
       int i, z;
       NSRange range;
       BOOL found;
       static NSMutableString *letters = nil;

       if ([word length] < 2) return NO;

       if(letters == nil) {
           letters = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:ltrs];
       }
       else {
           [letters setString: ltrs];
       }

       found = NO;
       range.length = 1;
       for(i = 0; i < [word length]; i++){
           for(z = 0; z < [letters length]; z++){
               if([word characterAtIndex:i] == [letters characterAtIndex:z]){
                    range.location = z;
                    [letters deleteCharactersInRange: range];
                    found = YES;
                    break;
               }
          }
          if (found == NO){
               return NO;
          }

          found = NO;
     }

     return YES;
   }
   ```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Haven't got an answer for you (yet) but there are some oddities in your code: You define the NSMutableString instance letters as nil. Then you check if it is nil and give it a value a few lines later. You could simply define it with the received ltrs parameter immediately.

Comment: A [pre-populated coredata db](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=core+data+prepopulate+tutorial#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&q=core+data+prepopulate+tutorial&oq=core+data+prepopulate+tutorial) would be the way to go...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Objective-C so I won't try to write a proper answer, but in general a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) offers a very effective data structure for sets of natural language words. You could even let the 'end of word' marker be an object representing the set of letters, or just an integer with the score pre-calculated.

Comment: @Christoffer How a `Trie` helps with checking sets of letters? Note that the problem doesn't take in account the ordering of letters in a word.

Comment: @Sulthan whoops, must have missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change few things to speed up.

1. Use fast enumeration in place of old C-style loop.
2. Avoid a lot of method calls.
3. Use NSPredicate and/or Regex if possible.

---

As whenever you write `[letters length]` a method is called, instead of finding it millions of time (this is inside 3rd level of nested loop), store it in a variable and use it.

Fast enumeration : Instead of `for(int i=0; i<[someArrays count];i++)` use `for(id object in someArrays)`.

Comment: putted [letter length] in an variable made it faster. Thanks. Could you explain a little bit more how to use fast enumeration and NSPredicate?

Comment: Google and SO are your best friend, I am not. I demand for vote up and reputations :p  **check update in my answer**

Comment: Example of predicate is shown by amar, follow him.

Answer (score 2):

Use this
`[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(fetchWords:) toTarget:self withObject:data];`

Do not do it in main thread

use this code modify it if u need to search words

```
NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSString *term in arryOfWordsToBeSearched) {
        NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains[cd] %@",term];
        [subpredicates addObject:p];
        }

     NSPredicate *filter = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];
    result = (NSMutableArray*)[arryOfDummyData filteredArrayUsingPredicate: filter];
```

//result is a array

Comment: if you need more code then cmnt

Comment: Run it in another thread might help some, but I still want to try to speed the execution up. When the user begins his round, 12 seconds is to long to wait for all the possibles word to be updated.

Comment: You need nspredicate to serch the relevent word it will speed up a little

Comment: I get no result from the Predicate

Comment: I pasted it from my working code you might need to modify @"self contains[cd] %@" this line accordingly please paste your code

Comment: NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];
    
    for (NSString *term in wordList)
    {
        NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", term];
        [subpredicates addObject:p];
    }

    NSPredicate *filter = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];
    NSMutableArray *result = (NSMutableArray *)[wordList filteredArrayUsingPredicate: filter];

Comment: In my code "arryOfWordsToBeSearched" is the words which i want to search..you have used wordlist in both cases

Comment: In my case i had to apply search predict kind of thing in case of word  game you will have one word only i guess

Comment: If it helps you can accept answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just for starters, create a `NSCharacterSet` from your `letters` and call this function before calling the lengthy function. This is a faster check to reduce the possibilities and it should improve your computation time.

```
NSCharacterSet* lettersSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:letters];

- (BOOL)isWordValid:(NSString*)word forLettersSet:(NSCharacterSet*)lettersSet {
    if ([word length] < 2) return NO;

    NSCharacterSet* wordLetters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:word];

    return [lettersSet isSupersetOfSet:wordLetters];
}
```

Ideally, your word database should have precomputed the letter count for each word (e.g. `every = {e=2, r=1, v=1, y=1}` and your should work only with these structures. Note that the order of letters is not significant - using this fact can greatly improve the performance of your algorithm.

You can also try to create a Core Data database - every word will be one record with a number field for every letter. Then you can create a request which will return you the available words VERY fast.
(Of course, the database will probably take bigger amount of space).

EDIT: Now I have found out `NSCountedSet` class, so let's try to use it:

```
-(NSCountedSet*)lettersSetFromString:(NSString*)string {
    NSCountedSet* letters = [NSCountedSet set];
    [string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.length)  
                               options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences   
                            usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        [letters addObject:substring];
    }];
} 

-(NSMutableArray *)validWordsForLetters:(NSString*)letters {
    NSCountedSet* lettersSet = [self lettersSetFromString:letters];

    NSMutableArray* results = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString* word in wordList) {
        if ([word length] < 2) {
            continue;
        }

        NSCountedSet* wordLettersSet = [self lettersSetFromString:word];

        if ([wordLettersSet isSubsetOfSet:lettersSet]) {
            [results addObject:word];
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Generating the counted sets for every word beforehand will help the perfomance a lot. Using a Core Data database will still be faster and better for the OS memory.

Comment: Thanks. That speeded it up a little :)

Comment: added `NSCountedSet` implementation as it will make the code simpler and probably faster.

Comment: Thanks for example. However, NSCountedSet made it slower

Comment: @user1251004 Interesting. Probably the implementation is too generic and that makes it slow. If your want to stay with in-memory search, maybe you should try different implementations with different inputs and then for every word choose one based on the length of the word + number of letters. For example, for 3 letter words you can probably skip the initial check from my post and go straight for your initial implementation. On the other hand, for 10+ letter words the `NSCountedSet` implementation could be faster. You will have to check it.

Comment: @user1251004 Also, you should add a `[word length] <= [letters length]` check to the beggining.

Comment: Aaand, as the last comment - even if `NSCountedSet` based comparison algorithm is slower, you can try to use it in your original algorithm instead of the `NSArray letter`, maybe that will help.